# Is there a way to use GetFileTime or Win API to account for DST time change on FAT32 without restarting the computer to update the FAT32 UTC cache?

Tags: winapi, timestamp, ntfs, fat32

I am looking for a way to account for DST time changes in file modified timestamps on FAT32 without having to restart the computer first after DST takes effect. As it is now I can only account for DST by restarting the computer after DST occurs. I have a program that compares an NTFS file to a copy of it on a FAT32 filesystem and needs to detect if the file has been modified or not by comparing modified timestamps.

Here are the results of FileTimeToLocalFileTime and LocalFileTimeToFileTime comparing the difference in seconds between the NTFS source file and the FAT32 file. As you can see DST is not accounted for until after restart. I am Pacific Standard Time UTC - 8. [This webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times) explains the details. I have no problem with using STL or something like that as long as it can account for USA DST and hopefully other country's DSTs as well.

```
before restart

FileTimeToLocalFileTime applied to FAT32 file: NTFSSourceFile timestamp - fat32filetime timestamp 0
LocalFileTimeToFileTime applied to FAT32 file: NTFSSourceFile timestamp - fat32filetime timestamp -960

after restart

FileTimeToLocalFileTime applied to FAT32 file: NTFSSourceFile timestamp - fat32filetime timestamp -60
LocalFileTimeToFileTime applied to FAT32 file: NTFSSourceFile timestamp - fat32filetime timestamp -1040
```

Comment: Are you caching the timestamps from the filesystem in some way, or reading them fresh each time? If the latter, it must be the filesystem caching the timezone offset - there may not be a way to force it to update.

Comment: I'm using GetFileTime. So I'm guessing the latter. That page I linked to details the situation with FAT32.

Comment: Are you opening the file handle specifically to call GetFileTime or do you already have it open when the time changes?

Comment: Open specifically to call GetFileTime.

Comment: Try using `setlocale` before `GetFileTime/GetLocalTime`, it may have unexpected effects.

Comment: After reading through the link you provided, I don't think there is a solution to the problem. Local time is inherently ambiguous: When going from DST to standard time, there is an entire hour's worth of timestamps that mean two things. If FAT does indeed store file times as local time, those timestamps do not reliably describe a point in time. This isn't specific to DST scenarios: If you mailed a FAT drive from Seattle, WA to Boston, MA, all timestamps for files written in the former and read in the latter are wrong.

Comment: There are alternatives to `GetFileTime`: 1. `GetFileAttributesEx`; 2. `GetFileInformationByHandle`; 3. `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`/`FILE_BASIC_INFO`. Would any of these work differently from `GetFileTime` in that regard?

Comment: Do the Qt framework with QFileInfo.lastModified() and c++ STL with std::filesystem::last_write_time probably use the win API behind the scenes? So do they have the same shortcomings as mentioned in this thread?

Comment: Also more information about this here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1144/Beating-the-Daylight-Savings-Time-bug-and-getting